# Connecting a Database to android studio

Tags: android, database

I am creating a quiz on android studio and I want my questions to be saved to the database and then called when needed. I am new to both Android studio and Databases. 
I have created a quiz on android Studio but it does not use a database. 
Does anyone have any advice on what database I should use and how to do it?
Thank you in Advance
Katy

Comment: Hi , You can use SQLite database for android http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ and http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Search for a tutorial on android and sqlite

Comment: You can use SQLite database for saving data, Tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ or Realm which is NoSQL based storage: https://realm.io/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use SQLite database for your project, as it is easy for beginners and already a part of Android SDK. Before you start coding for SQLite I think you should go for quick tutorial for it. [Like this one.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

This one will introduce you to the basics of how you should connect to database and basic CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete) operations.

Once you are good with database queries and operations, (and ofcourse tired of writing long SQL queries) you can definately move to some of the ORMs.

ORMs provide you quick access to your database entities. You will love them. Some of the good ORMs are :-

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) (Annotation based, good but slow)
[GreenDao](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/) (fast, but will take some time to learn how to use)